# Check if we are in new media uploader or Media->Add new / WordPress

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

I work on a new a plugin which get possible to move uploade image/file immediately after the uploading to custom folder. I have problem with a new media uploader (from WP 3.5). I have function which move the uploaded file and generate attachment metadata. I call this function via `add_action(add_attachment, '_the_function')`. The problem is that for finishing this action the classic media library need to print the attachment ID on the end of the function: `echo $post_ID` and the new media uploader need return json data `return wp_send_json_success( $attachment )`.

How can I check if I upload media via new media uploader or in Media->Add New.

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', array($this, 'up_move_media_after_add_attachment') );

function up_move_media_after_add_attachment( $post_ID ) {

    //... foregoing code (moving to custom folder) ...

    # generates metadata for an image attachment and creates a thumbnail and other intermediate sizes of the image attachment
    $metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $post_ID, get_attached_file( $post_ID ) );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata ( $post_ID, $metadata );

    if ( ___???????___ ) {
        # upload from post via new media uploader, since 3.5
        $attachment = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $post_ID );
        return wp_send_json_success( $attachment );

    } else {
        # upload from media library
        echo $post_ID;

        # don't forget
        exit;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found following solution:

```
if ( basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) == 'media-new.php' ):
    # upload from media library
    echo $post_ID;
    # don't forget
    exit;
else :
    # upload from post via new media uploader, since 3.5
    $attachment = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $post_ID );
    return wp_send_json_success( $attachment );
endif;
```